# disable sidekiq in staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I've got ***sidekiq*** set up for in a rails app and everything is fine.

Now I want to disable it for ***stagin env*** only.

I can just change the **redis password** in YML file, but I am sure there must a better (more elegant way) to stop workers in only one env.

BTW, I kill the process in the box but every time I deploy to staging (***capistrano-sidekiq***), it creates a new process.

Comment: commented or remove `capistrano-sidekiq`

Comment: ? I use `capistrano-sidekiq` for deployment to production (where I still want worker to be scheduled/run)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
require 'capistrano-sidekiq' if fetch(:stage) != 'staging'
```

Comment: `NameError: undefined local variable or method "rails_env" for main:Object` in Capfile

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "something like".

Comment: Looks like `if fetch(:stage) == 'production'` might work.